# determine whether Web Storage is supported or not

Tags: javascript, local-storage, web-storage, session-storage

I need to verify that Web Storage API is supported and available (it may be disabled due to security issues).

So, I thought it would suffice to check whether the type sessionStorage or localStorage is defined or not:

```
if (typeof sessionStorage != 'undefined')
{
    alert('sessionStorage available');
}
else
{
    alert('sessionStorage not available');
}
```

However, I was wondering if it could be possible that the type exists, but I wouldn't been able to use the Web Storage API anyway.

Remarks:
I know Firefox will throw a security error if cookies are disabled and sessionStorage or localStorage are accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, because `Modernizr.localstorage` respectively  `Modernizr.sessionstorage` will return true while Firefox might be used with disabled Cookies (which will lead into an security error) or any other proprietary (unexpected) behavior could occur: I've written my own `webStorageEnabled` function which seems to work very well.

```
function cookiesEnabled()
{
    // generate a cookie to probe cookie access
    document.cookie = '__cookieprobe=0;path=/';
    return document.cookie.indexOf('__cookieprobe') != -1;
}

function webStorageEnabled()
{
    if (typeof webStorageEnabled.value == 'undefined')
    {
        try
        {
            localStorage.setItem('__webstorageprobe', '');
            localStorage.removeItem('__webstorageprobe');
            webStorageEnabled.value = true;
        }
        catch (e) {
            webStorageEnabled.value = false;
        }
    }

    return webStorageEnabled.value;
}


// conditional

var storage = new function()
{
    if (webStorageEnabled())
    {
        return {
            local:   localStorage,
            session: sessionStorage
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return {
            local: cookiesEnabled() ? function()
            {
                // use cookies here
            }() : null,

            session: function()
            {
                var data = {};

                return {
                    clear: function () {
                        data = {};
                    },

                    getItem: function(key) {
                        return data[key] || null;
                    },

                    key: function(i)
                    {
                        var index = 0;
                        for (var value in data)
                        {
                            if (index == i)
                                return value;
                            ++index;
                        }
                    },

                    removeItem: function(key) {
                        delete data[key];
                    },

                    setItem: function(key, value) {
                        data[key] = value + '';
                    }
                };
            }()
        };
    }
}
```

Hope this will be useful for someone too.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use the [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) library to detect if local storage is supported or not? Any differences between browers will be taken care of for you, you can then just use code like this:

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    // browser supports local storage
} else {
    // browser doesn't support local storage
}
```

Comment: Hum, that won't work with Firefox and disabled Cookies. I've tested it and still got an security error.

Comment: @SaschaHoll - what error are you getting? Which version of Firefox? It works fine for me in Firefox 8.0.

Comment: Same version here. You need to disable cookies. It won't work if you do (see my latest answer).

Comment: I've tried it with cookies enabled (Modernizr.localstorage is true) and cookies disabled (Modernizr.localstorage is false) - no error on screen or in the console output.

Comment: Hum, that's weird. So, you've unchecked "accept cookies from sites"? If I do so, `Modernizr.localstorage` is true and an security error is raised.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're on the right track with your original code, no need to make this too fancy.

Using the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) with no additional dependencies in your code:

```
var storageEnabled = function() {
    try {
        sessionStorage.setItem('test-key','test-value');
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('test-key') == 'test-value'){
            return true;
        }
    } catch (e) {};
    return false;
};

alert(storageEnabled() ? 'sessionStorage available' : 'sessionStorage not available');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    ssSupport = Object.prototype.toString.call( sessionStorage ) === "[object Storage]";
}
catch(e){
    ssSupport = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version (because IE 9 running in IE 8 more on an intranet site is broken).

```
if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined" && !!sessionStorage.getItem) {

}
```

a longer version that adds setObject to allow storing objects:

```
var sstorage;

if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined" && !!sessionStorage.getItem) {
    Storage.prototype.setObject = function (key, value) {
        this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    };

    Storage.prototype.getObject = function (key) {
        return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key));
    };
    if (typeof sessionStorage.setObject == "function") {
        sstorage = sessionStorage;
    }
    else {
        setupOldBrowser();
    }
}
else {
    setupOldBrowser();
}


function setupOldBrowser() {
    sstorage = {};
    sstorage.setObject = function (key, value) {
        this[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    };
    sstorage.getObject = function (key) {
        if (typeof this[key] == 'string') {
            return JSON.parse(this[key]);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    };

    sstorage.removeItem = function (key) {
        delete this[key];
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do to use session storage if available if it's not, use cookies..

```
var setCookie; 
var getCookie;

var sessionStorageSupported = 'sessionStorage' in window 
                                   && window['sessionStorage'] !== null;

if (sessionStorageSupported) {
    setCookie = function (cookieName, value) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem(cookieName, value);
        return value; //you can introduce try-catch here if required
    };
    getCookie = function (cookieName) {
        return window.sessionStorage.getItem(cookieName);
    };
}
else {
    setCookie = function (cookieName, value) {
        $.cookie(cookieName, value);
        return value; // null if key not present
    };
    getCookie = function(cookieName) {
        console.log("using cookies");
        return $.cookie(cookieName);
    };
}
```